# Xcode11 or Transporter suck at "authenticating with the app store"

Tags: ios, xcode11, application-loader

Ihave tried this

```
（1）cd ~
（2）mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
（3） "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
```

or this

```
 cd ~
 mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
 "/Applications/Transporter.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

always get stuck in this place
[image]

and this
[image]

Comment: Try to do the operation with open network where firewall is not restricting anything.